# Change header after \section

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

My TeX document has a `\section with a too long text, so I'd like to change header by` \markright` with something like that^

```
\section{Too long text}
\markright{\thesection. Shorter text}
```

However, as the help promises, right header is set by the first `\markright` or `\markboth` on the page, so with the code above the header contains Too long text (generated by `\section`).
The code

```
\markright{\thesection. Shorter text}
\section{Too long text}
```

gives almost what is required, excepting the text number which is 1 less that it should, because increasing `\section` is just below. So, it is needed to write something like

```
\stepcounter{section}
\markright{\thesection. Shorter text}
\addtocounter{section}{-1}
\section{Too long text}
```

It gives solution, but seems too tricky for so simple task. There is optional argument in `\section` but it changes not only header, but also line in the contents, which is not needed.

So, is it possible to change header after `\section' in a simple way?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330550/full-section-title-in-table-of-contents

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\rmfamily \small \nouppercase \rightmark}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\section{Abstract \protect\markboth{Abstract}{Abstract} }

\kant[1]

\clearpage

\section{A very long title perhaps two lines \protect\markboth{Short title I }{Short title I}}
\kant[2-5]

\clearpage

\section{A much  longer  title perhaps two lines  o more A much  longer  title perhaps two lines  o more \protect\markboth{Short title II}{Short title II}}
\kant[6-9]           
    
\clearpage
\section{Normal title}
\kant[10-12] 


\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the headers anyway, because the style with uppercase slanted titles is really awful.

I propose a `\doubletitle` command, to be used for long section (or chapter) titles; the first argument is the long title, the second one is the short form.

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\shorttrue\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\shorttrue\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newif\ifshort
\DeclareRobustCommand{\doubletitle}[2]{\ifshort #2\else #1\fi}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Title}

\section{\doubletitle{First Here we have a very very very very very very very very very
  very very very very very very very very very very very very long title}{First}}

\lipsum[1-20]

\section{\doubletitle{Second Here we have a very very very very very very very very very
  very very very very very very very very very very very very long title}{Second}}

\lipsum[1-20]

\section{Short title}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

You might consider using `memoir` instead of `book` that has a built in mechanism with two optional arguments for the sectional commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `memoir` class (encompasses the `book`, `report` and `article`) classes. Document divisions may take two optional arguments for the ToC text, and separately the heading text. For example:

```
\section{<toc-title>][<head-title>]{<title>}
```

- no optional arguments `<title>` used in ToC, header, and document; `<title>` is always used for the document.
- one optional argument `<toc-title>` used for ToC and header.
- two optional arguments `<toc-title>` for the ToC, `<head-title>` for the header.